# Use two random function to get a specific random funciton

Tags: algorithm, math

There are two random functions f1(),f2().

f1() returns 1 with probability p1, and 0 with probability 1-p1.

f2() returns 1 with probability p2, and 0 with probability 1-p2.

I want to implement a new function f3() which returns 1 with probability p3(***a given probability***), and returns 0 with probability 1-p3. In the implemetion of function f3(), we can use function f1() and f2(), but you can't use any other random function.

If p3=0.5, an example of implemention:

```
int f3()
{
    do
    {
        int a = f1();
        int b = f1();
        if (a==b) continue;
        // when reachs here 
        // a==1 with probability p1(1-p1)
        // b==1 with probability (1-p1)p1
        if (a==1) return 1;//now returns 1 with probability 0.5
        if (b==1) return 0;
    }while(1)
}
```

This implemention of f3() will give a random function returns 1 with probability 0.5, and 0 with probability 0.5. But how to implement the f3() with p3=0.4? I have no idea.

I wonder, is that task possible? And how to implement f3()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relation between `f3()` and `f1(),f2()`?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman In the implemetion of function f3(), we can use function f1() and f2().

Comment: so what is `p3` ?  In your example implementation `p3 == p1`, but I'm sure that's not what you meant.

Comment: @Alnitak a given probability. You can take p3 as a input of this problem

Comment: If you use different probability `p3`, then why you need to use `f1(), f2()` in `f3()`?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman The only random function you can use is f1() and f2(). and p3 is given first and specific.

Comment: @Sayakiss the question is still nonsense.  Did you perhaps want it to return `f1()` with probability `p3`, and `f2()` with probability `1 - p3` ?

Comment: @Alnitak no,I want to it returns 1 with p3

Comment: And `p1` and `p2` are known?  Also, is this math homework?

Comment: @Alnitak known, not homework, My friend gives me this question.

Comment: Did the friend mentioned the relation between p1, p2, and p3? I feel like the puzzle contains this relation.

Comment: @Dialecticus no relation. My friend ask me to solve a simple version with p3=0.5. I use the implemention above. Then my friend ask me to think about p3 is given probability(0<p3<1). We both have no idea.

Comment: Uhm, what makes you think that the `p3` you show above will return 1 with probability 0.5 and 0 with probability 0.5? I don't see why that's necessarily the case, your fancy comment notwithstanding.

Comment: it's because a and b are generated from the very same distribution. if they are not equal (which is impossible, since we are on the else part of that if statement), then either a=1 and b=0 or vice versa. whether the 1 is a or it is b is 50%, because they are coming from the same distribution.

Comment: @NikBougalis when go beyond the "continue", the case of "a==1" and 
"b==1" with the same probability.

Comment: personally I think, this is a really interesting question, and I'm afraid it's only getting many downvotes, because people just don't understand it perfectly.

Comment: @elias can't agree any more. I have discussed this problem with my friend for hours.

Comment: It is possible iff p3 = A(p1,p2)/B(p1,p2) where A, B - some polynomials with integer coefficients in two variables.

Comment: @Sayakiss Yeah. I read that wrong: I saw it as if `a` was initialized with `f1()` and `b` with `f2()`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, could you please go into details? I can see how we could construate f3 if p3 = q*(p1)^r1*(1-p1)^r2*(p2)^r3*(1-p2)^r4 (q is rational, rns are integers), but am lost with general integer-coefficient polynoms, and their ratio. thanks!

Comment: @elias - Imagine a hypercube with edges length = 1, dissected by hyperplains x_i=p1 or x_i=p2.  You can select any set of subvolumes as 1-event and any other non-intersecting set as 0-event, so p3=v1/(v0+v1), where v0, v1 - total volumes of selected sets.

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff, so the fraction comes from the idea of conditional probabilities. However, I still cannot see, what form v0 and v1 might take. I'm quite sure that not all integer-coefficient polynoms will do (e.g. 1+p1 is not even in the proper interval), but I would say they are finite sums of expressions with the form I described above - but not every finite sum will do either, we have to provide the empty intersection you have mentioned. Am I right?

Comment: @elias - Of course, A/B must be between 0 and 1.  Give an example of polynomials A and B you consider non-implementable.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - Not only A/B, but also A and B separately should be between 0 and 1, I think. I would much more like to see a general solution with some rigorous proof, but ok, let's try it with an example. I won't go too far, if basic operations work, a much more complex polynom can be built up step by step, so I'm interested in the p3=p1+p2 and p3=p1-p2 cases.

Comment: @elias - Sorry, I was wrong.  For "subhypercubes-combinations" method to work `p3` must be of the form `A(1/p1-1,1/p2-1)/B(1/p1-1,1/p2-1)` where `A`, `B` and `B-A` are polynomials in two variables with non-negative integer coefficients.   So, with this approach `p1+p2` and `p1-p2` are impossible.  But maybe another approach exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
p1 = 0.77  -- arbitrary value between 0 and 1

function f1()
   if math.random() < p1 then
      return 1
   else
      return 0
   end
end

-- f1() is enough.  We don't need f2()

p3 = 0.4 -- arbitrary value between 0 and 1

--------------------------

function f3()
   left = 0
   rigth = 1
   repeat
      middle = left + (right - left) * p1
      if f1() == 1 then 
         right = middle
      else
         left = middle
      end
      if right < p3 then     -- completely below 
         return 1
      elseif left >= p3 then -- completely above 
         return 0
      end
   until false  -- loop forever
end
```

Comment: @Sayakiss - The idea is to implement infinitely running function of generating random point on interval `[0,1)` by sequentially narrowing result window.  We stops execution of the function when the result window is completely below or completely above the `p3`-threshold.

Comment: But why it will return 1 will probability p3?

Comment: Your solution is the best!

Comment: And the expectation steps of your solution is (1-p1^2-(1-p1)^2)^(-1). Assuming p3 is uniformly distributed in [0,1)

Comment: @Sayakiss - Yes.  You can change the algorithm by using both functions (`f1` and `f2`) to reduce expected steps ;-)

Comment: @Sayakiss - No, on each step you should decide what function to use (4 variants: `f1`, `f2`, `!f1`, `!f2`).

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved if p3 is a rational number.

We should use conditional probabilities for this.

For example, if you want to make this for p3=0.4, the method is the following:

Calculate the fractional form of p3. In our case it is p3=0.4=2/5.

Now generate as many random variables from the same distribution (let's say, from f1, we won't use f2 anyway) as the denominator, call them X1, X2, X3, X4, X5.
We should regenerate all these random X variables until their sum equals the numerator in the fractional form of p3.

Once this is achieved then we just return X1 (or any other Xn, where n was chosen independently of the values of the X variables). Since there are 2 1s among the 5 X variables (because their sum equals the numerator), the probability of X1 being 1 is exactly p3.

For irrational p3, the problem cannot be solved by using only f1. I'm not sure now, but I think, it can be solved for p3 of the form p1*q+p2*(1-q), where q is rational with a similar method, generating the appropriate amount of Xs with distribution f1 and Ys with distribution f2, until they have a specific predefined sum, and returning one of them. This still needs to be detailed.

Answer (score 2):

First to say, that's a nice problem to tweak one's brain. I managed to solve the problem for `p3 = 0.4`, for what you just asked for! And I think, generalisation of such problem, is not so trivial. :D

**Here is how, you can solve it for `p3 = 0.4`:**

The intuition comes from your example. If we generate a number from `f1()` five times in an iteration, (***see the code bellow***), we can have **32** types of results like bellow:

```
 1: 00000
 2: 00001
 3: 00010
 4: 00011
    .....
    .....
32: 11111
```

Among these, there are **10** such results with exactly two `1`'s in it! After identifying this, the problem becomes simple. Just return `1` for any of the 4 combinations and return `0` for 6 others! (as probability 0.4 means getting `1`, 4 times out of 10). You can do that like bellow:

```
  int f3()
 {
     do{
          int a[5];
          int numberOfOneInA = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
               a[i] = f1();
               if(a[i] == 1){
                 numberOfOneInA++;  
               }
          }

          if (numberOfOneInA != 2) continue;           
          else return a[0]; //out of 10 times, 4 times a[0] is 1!

     }while(1)
}
```

Waiting to see a generalised solution.
Cheers!

Comment: you've implemented exactly what I described: basically you return a[0] on those ten long lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea that will work when `p3` is of a form `a/2^n` (a rational number with a denominator that is a power of 2).

Generate `n` random numbers with probability distribution of `0.5`:

> x1, x2, ..., xn

Interpret this as a binary number in the range `0...2^n-1`; each number in this range has equal probability. If this number is less than `a`, return 1, else return 0.

Now, since this question is in a context of computer science, it seems reasonable to assume that `p3` is in a form of `a/2^n` ([this a common representation of numbers in computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)).

Answer (score 1):

I implement the idea of anatolyg and Egor:

```
inline double random(void)
{
    return static_cast<double>(rand()) / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX);
}

const double p1 = 0.8;
int rand_P1(void)
{
    return random() < p1;
}

int rand_P2(void)//return 0 with 0.5
{
    int x, y; while (1)
    {
        mystep++;
        x = rand_P1(); y = rand_P1();
        if (x ^ y) return x;
    }
}

double p3 = random();
int rand_P3(void)//anatolyg's idea
{
    double tp = p3; int bit, x;
    while (1)
    {
        if (tp * 2 >= 1) {bit = 1; tp = tp * 2 - 1;}
        else {bit = 0; tp = tp * 2;}
        x = rand_P2();
        if (bit ^ x) return bit;
    }
}

int rand2_P3(void)//Egor's idea
{
    double left = 0, right = 1, mid;
    while (1)
    {
        dashenstep++;
        mid = left + (right - left) * p1;
        int x = rand_P1();
        if (x) right = mid; else left = mid;
        if (right < p3) return 1;
        if (left > p3) return 0;
    }
}
```

With massive math computings, I get, assuming P3 is uniformly distributed in [0,1), then the expectation of Egor is (1-p1^2-(1-p1)^2)^(-1). And anatolyg is 2(1-p1^2-(1-p1)^2)^(-1).

Answer (score 0):

Speaking Algorithmically , Yes It is possible to do that task done .

Even Programmatically , It is possible , but a complex problem .

Lets take an example .

Let 
F1(1) = .5 which means  F1(0) =.5
F2(2) = .8 which means  F1(0) =.2

Let Suppose You need a F3, such that F3(1)= .128

Lets try Decomposing it .

```
 .128
= (2^7)*(10^-3) // decompose this into know values 
= (8/10)*(8/10)*(2/10) 
= F2(1)&F2(1)*(20/100) // as no Fi(1)==2/10 
= F2(1)&F2(1)*(5/10)*(4/10)
= F2(1)&F2(1)&F1(1)*(40/100)
= F2(1)&F2(1)&F1(1)*(8/10)*(5/10)
= F2(1)&F2(1)&F1(1)&F2(1)&F1(1)
```

So F3(1)=.128 if we define F3()=F2()&F2()&F2()&F1()&F1()

Similarly if you want F4(1)=.9 ,

You give it as F4(0)=F1(0) | F2(0) =F1(0)*F2(0)=.5*.2 =.1 ,which mean F4(1)=1-0.1=0.9

Which means F4 is zero only when both are zero which happens .

So making use  this ( & , | and , not(!) , xor(^) if you want ) operations with a combinational use of f1,f2 will surely give you the F3 which is made purely out of f1,f2,

Which may be NP hard problem to find the combination which gives you the exact probability.

So, Finally the answer to your question , whether it is possible or not ? is **YES** and this is one way of doing it, may be many hacks can be made into it this to optimize this, which gives you any optimal way .

Comment: Unless you have a proper proof that it's NP-hard, don't state your guesses as facts.

Comment: I admit . Corrected that in my Answer .